# How to find the clock speed my fpga runs in XPS or EDK?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, virtex-series-fpga

I created a custom ip and added it to my design. I want to find out the speed of the clock. Is there any menu/option to find out in Xillinx platform studio or EDK?

Comment: Clock speed is usually derived from the hardware external to the FPGA. So how can software know about it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. The cpu is set at 50Mhz, it's a heterogeneous system. So it takes 20ns to run the vhdl logic?

Answer (score 1):

You can check in the .mhs file that is created by EDK. In this file you will find a clock generator. Trace the input and output of this clock generator to know which IP runs at which frequency.